# Using the uniqueness theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| > 1 \}$ , $B= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid z \neq 0\}$. Then how to prove that there is a non-constant analytic function from $A$ to $B$ and not from $B$ to $A$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: From $A$ to $B$ take the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $f:B\to A$ is analytic. Consider $g=1/f.$

Comment: Can you please explain it A bit more!?

Comment: $|f|>1$ so $|1/f|<1.$

Comment: Then how can i use uniqueness theorem? Can you explain this from the beginning?

Comment: I'm not thnking of the uniqueness theorem. $1/f$ has a removable singularity at $0,$ hence the extended $1/f$ is constant by Liouville.

Comment: Okay okay! Got it